# Reward package doesn't appear in google_play_service_lib

Tags: admob, ads

I'm getting stuck with this... I am trying to implement RewardedVideoAd that is included in the package reward on `google_play_service_lib`. But in the `google_play_service_lib` that I imported, such package does not appear, so I get an error when I try to import the reward package.

Anyone knows how to get this to implement `rewardedAds`?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post what the error is?

Comment: Eclipse says "the type could not be resolved" when I make the import. I didn't find anything on Internet where anyone can see how to deploy rewarded Ads in Eclipse